# How do you find the interval for an integral whose area is a given number?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm not sure what the mathematical term for this is, because I took calculus a long time ago but how would we go about solving this problem.

For instance. Find $b$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{b} \frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=1,1$$

Also what is the name for this type of problem. Is it the same as a definite integral?

Comment: Notice that your integral is a divergent improper integral.

Comment: @GSofer I realized as I posted the problem. My main question is about finding the interval for a given area under a curve where one of the numbers is given and the other we have to solve for. Hypothetically if the interval was say 1 to b instead of 0 to b

Comment: @JohnLee If you need to find  $b$ such that $\int_{1}^{b}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}$, so you need to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus. For, example, in that case you have $\int_{1}^{b}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2} \implies -\frac{1}{b}-\left(-\frac{1}{1}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \implies b=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Generally (for a different integrand), you use the fundamental theorem of calculus. If you wish for the integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ to be $k$, then:

$$\int_a^b f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)=_{demand}k$$
Assuming you know the primitive $F$, this usually comes down to solving for $b$ (there isn't always a way to do this, but for simple enough functions it's possible). For example, if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2},a=1,k=1.1$, then:
$$\int_1^b \frac{1}{t^2}dt=-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{1}=_{demand}1.1\Rightarrow b=-10$$

This is indeed called a definite integral.